# flower UI doesn't show workers

Tags: celery, airflow, flower

I have set up airflow to execute workflows with celeryExecuter. I have started the webserver, scheduler and worker and they run just fine. But flower UI doesn't show any workers.

The output of `airflow worker` is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-08-02 11:29:09,827] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-08-02 11:29:09,983] {driver.py:124} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-08-02 11:29:10,052] {driver.py:124} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
```

And the output of `airflow flower` is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
[2018-08-02 11:29:35,574] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-08-02 11:29:35,739] {driver.py:124} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-08-02 11:29:35,799] {driver.py:124} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[I 180802 11:29:36 command:139] Visit me at http://0.0.0.0:5555
[I 180802 11:29:36 command:144] Broker: amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
[I 180802 11:29:36 command:147] Registered tasks: 
    [u'celery.accumulate',
     u'celery.backend_cleanup',
     u'celery.chain',
     u'celery.chord',
     u'celery.chord_unlock',
     u'celery.chunks',
     u'celery.group',
     u'celery.map',
     u'celery.starmap']
[I 180802 11:29:36 mixins:224] Connected to amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
```

But flower doesn't show any information about workers or tasks and generates following error on CLI:

> [E 180802 11:29:55 broker:82] RabbitMQ management API call failed:
>   [Errno 111] Connection refused

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to solve the problem. It turns out I was supposed to add `export C_FORCE_ROOT=true` to my `~/.bashrc` file before running the worker. This happens when you're executing the worker as root.